# Abudraham on the Siddur - Edition

Tags: tefilla, product-recommendation, prayer-book

Can someone please recommend an edition of Abudraham's commentary on the siddur?

I am looking for an edition that is -
A) all-Hebrew b) pleasant to use, with clear print c) up to date (has parts of the commentary that were discovered after earlier editions were published).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The Machon Keren Re'eim publishing house has a beautiful [2-volume](https://www.shopeichlers.com/products/rabeinu-dovid-abudraham-2-volume-set/37253) and [3-volume](https://www.shopeichlers.com/products/rabeinu-dovid-abudraham-3-volume-set/37254) set. Sadly they both appear to be out of stock.

An older edition produced by Machon Even Yisroel which does not have as clear a text but is still very nicely printed can be found [here](https://seforimcenter.com/Abudraham-HaShalem-2-vol.__p-1327.aspx) and [here](https://mysefer.com/Abudraham-HaShalem-2-vol.__p-1327.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for these recommendations. What does the three-volume set have that the two volume does not?

Comment: I'm not actually sure to be honest

Comment: @Dov though out of stock at Eichlers, it seems like [JudaicaSpot](https://judaicaspot.com/products/%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95-%D7%93%D7%95%D7%93-%D7%90%D7%91%D7%95%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%94%D7%9D-%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%99-%D7%94%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%95%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%9F-%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9D-%D7%92%D7%9B) is still carrying it.